# Finding text within a span that contains tags and white spacing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following span that contains white-spacing and text within tags - in this case a sup tag and a p tag:

```
<span class="teamName">
                        Dr.<sup>J</sup>
                        W
                        Smith
                        <br>
                        <p class="department">Throat specialist</p>
                    </span>
```

I'm trying to extract 'Dr. J W Smith' from the element, but can't figure out how to do this. So far I have this:

`jQuery('span[class="teamName"]').text()`, which gives me the following output:

```
"
                        Dr.J
                        W
                        Smith

                        Throat specialist
                    "
```

This is as far as I got, I was thinking about stripping away the white spacing and placing each word in an array and then remove the last entry, does anybody have any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: You seem to have an idea on how to go about this? How does it not work?

Comment: Side note: To select by class, use a class selector (`.teamName`), not an attribute selector (`[class=teamName]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to clone the element, remove the `br` and `p` from it, and then get its text, replace any spans of whitespace with just a single space, and trim it:

```js
// Here I'm assuming you have more than one
// of these, so this produces an array
var names = jQuery("span.teamName")
              .clone()
              .find("br, p").remove().end()
              .map(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
}).get();
console.log(names);
```

```html
<span class="teamName">
                        Dr.<sup>J</sup>
                        W
                        Smith
                        <br>
                        <p class="department">Throat specialist</p>
                    </span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you just have one, we can avoid the `map`:

```js
// Here I'm assuming you have more than one
// of these, so this produces an array
var name = jQuery("span.teamName")
              .clone()
              .find("br, p").remove().end()
              .text()
              .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
              .trim();
console.log(name);
```

```html
<span class="teamName">
                        Dr.<sup>J</sup>
                        W
                        Smith
                        <br>
                        <p class="department">Throat specialist</p>
                    </span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I suppose you don't have to remove the `br` element, since it doesn't have any text...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clone()` function

```js
var cloned = $('.teamName').clone();

cloned.find('p').remove();
console.log(cloned.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="teamName">
                        Dr.<sup>J</sup>
                        W
                        Smith
                        <br>
                        <p class="department">Throat specialist</p>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```js
var $span = $('.teamName').clone();
$span.find('p').remove();
alert($span.text().replace(/[ \n]+/g, ' '));
```